# FOSRestBundle Routing Priority

Tags: symfony, routes, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOSRestBundle.

I want to match some routes to control if my redis server has key as same as the requested url.

My problem is, i want to do that before any controller or any other action called but FOSRestBundle catches the request first.

Note: If url has one or more "/" this is happenning. If has not, everything works fine.

For example:

> blabla.com/books/or-something-else <- Error!
>
> blabla.com/books-or-something-else <- Success, working fine!

I have a listener:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
        // dumping to see which controller makes the request
        var_dump($request->attributes->get('_controller')); die;
        return;
    }

    if ($request->attributes->has('_controller')) {
        // routing is already done
        return;
    }

    try {
        $route = $this->_match($request->getPathInfo());

        if($route == "" OR $route == false){
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("404");
        }
        else{
            $request->attributes->add($route);
        }
        
        unset($route["_route"],$route["_controller"]);
        $request->attributes->set("_route_params",$route);
    }
    catch(NotFoundHttpException $e){

    }
}
```

Service:

```
<service id="cs.routing" class="CS\CommonBundle\Utils\CSRouting">
    <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
    <argument>%redis%</argument>
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.request" method="onKernelRequest" priority="1" />
</service>
```